# Lazy evaluation of numpy.max

Tags: python, numpy, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

Suppose I have a 1D numpy array `x` with shape `(n,)` consisting mostly of zeros, and a 2D array `Y` with shape `(m,n)`. I want to compute

```
np.sum(x * np.max(Y,axis=0))
```

i.e. the dot product of `x` with the matrix `Y` flattened by taking the max of each column. If these arrays are large and `x` consists mostly of zeros, presumably I'm doing a lot of wasteful `max` operations.

Is there any way to do the computation in a lazy way, so that the max only gets computed for nonzero values? I'm looking for an elegant way - obviously, I could write a for loop and check for zero values.

Comment: Not sure it is related to functional programming, but `0*NaN=NaN`, `0*Infinity=NaN`, `0*-1=-0`

Comment: About the only thing that has a chance of improving speed is to use `mask=x!=0` to select columns or rows of `Y` for further processing.  I haven't worked out your dimensions to see if that's feasible.

Comment: `np.max(Y,1)` has shape (m,).  How does the `*` is (n,) shaped `x`?

Comment: I think @hpaulj has a good idea.  Here is how to implement it: `np.sum(x[mask]*np.max(Y[mask, :], axis=1))`.  But you need to test it on your actual data to see if it really is faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where` to find the non zero indices. For example (`m=3` and `n=6`):

```
x= np.array([1,0,0,2,3,1])
Y = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6],
              [4,5,6,1,2,3],
              [7,8,9,4,5,1]])
ind = np.where(x != 0)[0]
result = sum(x[ind]*np.max(Y[:,ind], axis=0))
print (result)
```

**Output**

```
36.0
```

Comment: Now you need to do some timings to determine when this is faster!

Comment: I leave it as the task of OP and post here the results in the interest of all.